# Printing from different printers without printing dialog using Vue and Spring

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, vue.js, multipartform-data

I am having a problem I hope u can help me with it. I am working on this project with Spring boot and Vuejs. I am supposed to print 3 unrelated different parts in the app without the printing dialog. and I am working with 3 different printers for each part of the app. I can't find a way to do that in the frontend because the browser doesn't allow that, So I thought of doing that through the backend So the first idea came to me is to convert the html element that I should print to pdf to do so I used html2pdf plugin to extract the file and then send it to the backend as multipartfile and in the backend I will use the printerjob class to do the printing. I used in the backend pdfbox (attached a code I used to work with the multipart file to be able to print it) but things didn't work out right. I go that error -> Error: End-of-File, expected line. which show that the file is empty. Now I don't know what I am doing wrong and don't have much experience with java to make it work. So if anyone can help me

this is the frontend part with converting the html to pdf

```
   let that = this;

      html2pdf()
        .set({
          filename: "test.pdf",
          margin: 4,
          jsPDF: {
            orientation: "portrait",
          },
        })
        .from(document.getElementById("voucher-body"))
        .toPdf()
        .output("datauristring")
        .then(function(pdfAsString) {
          const file = new File([pdfAsString], "voucher-body", {
            type: "application/pdf",
            lastModified: new Date().getTime(),
          });

          console.log(file);
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsText(file);
          reader.onload = () => console.log(reader.result);

          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("data", file);

          that.printForm({
            eventId: that.event.id,
            doctorId: that.doctor.id,
            type: "voucher",
            formFile: formData,
          });
        });
```

And this is the method to handle printing the multipart file in spring

`

```
 PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file.getInputStream());
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setJobName(file.getOriginalFilename());
//
        for (PrintService ps : PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices()) {
            String psName = ps.toString();
            // 选用指定打印机
            if (psName.equals("XP-80C (copy 1)")) {
                job.setPrintService(ps);
                break;
            }
        }
//
        job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));

        Paper paper = new Paper();
        // 设置打印纸张大小
        paper.setSize(598,842); // 1/72 inch
        // 设置打印位置 坐标
        paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight()); // no margins
        // custom page format
        PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
        pageFormat.setPaper(paper);
        // override the page format
        Book book = new Book();
        // append all pages 设置一些属性 是否缩放 打印张数等
        book.append(new PDFPrintable(document, Scaling.ACTUAL_SIZE), pageFormat, 1);
        job.setPageable(book);
        // 开始打印
        job.print();`
```